# Including DirectShow library into Qt for video thumbnail

Tags: windows, qt, directshow, thumbnails

I'm trying to implement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377634%28v=VS.85%29.aspx on Qt, to generate a poster frame/thumbnail for video files.

I have installed both Windows Vista and Windows 7 SDK. I put:

```
#include "qedit.h"
```

in my code (noting there is also one in C:\Qt\2010.04\mingw\include), I add:

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:/WindowsSDK/v6.0/Include)
```

to my *.pro file. I compile and get " error: sal.h: No such file or directory". Finding this in VC++ I add

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include)
```

And now have 1400 compile errors. So, I abandon that and just add:

win32:LIBS += C:/WindowsSDK/v7.1/Lib/strmiids.lib

to my *.pro file and try to run (without including any headers):

```
IMediaDet mediadet;
```

But then I get "error: IMediaDet: No such file or directory".

```
#include "qedit.h"
```

gives me the same error (it looks like it's pointing to the Qt version) and

```
#include "C:/WindowsSDK/v6.0/Include/qedit.h"
```

goes back to generating 1000's of compile errors.

Sigh, so much trouble for what should be 10 lines of code...

Thanks for your comments and help

Comment: I took the liberty to format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are "a C++/Qt newbie" then I suspect that the real issue may be that you are attempting to load the library yourself rather than simply linking your application to it?

To link an external library into your application with Qt all you need to do is modify the appropriate `.pro` file. For example if the library is called `libfoo.dll` you just add

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/lib -lfoo
```

You can find more information about this in [the relevant section of the qmake manual](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs). Note that `qmake` commonly employs Unix-like notation and transparently does the right thing on Windows.

Having done this you can include the library's headers and use whatever classes and functions it provides. Note that you can also modify the project file to append an include path to help pick up the headers eg.

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/headers
```

Again, more information in [the relevant section of the qmake manual](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath).

Note that both these project variables work with relative paths and will happily work with `..` to mean "go up a directory" on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Note that qedit.h requires dxtrans.h, which is part of DirectX9 SDK.

You can find dxtrans.h in DirectX SDK from [August 2006](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c72d9f1e-53f3-4747-8490-6801d8e8b4ef). Note that dxtrans.h is removed from newer DirectX SDKs.

Comment: I find it amusing that it was easier for me to cross compile FFmpeg on Linux and use avcodec.dll to create thumbnails than get the Windows API working in Qt. Anyhow, I'll return to this when space and speed becomes and issue. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Microsoft has deprecated DirectShow and DirectShow Editing Services (qedit.h is part of DES). For example on Windows Server 2008 (normal and R2) qedit.dll is not present.

When you have the right SDKs programming DirectShow works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the source of the external library? The following assumes that you do.

What I do when I need to extract a class from a library with only functions resolved, is to use a factory function in the library.

```
// Library.h
class SomeClass {
public:
  SomeClass(std::string name);
  // ... class declaration goes here
};
```

In the cpp file, I use a proxy function outside the extern "C" when my constructor requires C++ parameters (e.g. types such as std::string), which I pass as a pointer to prevent the compiler from messing up the signature between C and C++. You can avoid the extra step if your constructor doesn't require parameters, and call new SomeClass() directly from the exported function.

```
// Library.cpp
#include "Library.h"
SomeClass::SomeClass(std::string name)
{
// implementation details
}

// Proxy function to handle C++ types
SomeClass *ImplCreateClass(std::string* name) { return new SomeClass(*name); }

extern "C"
{
  // Notice the pass-by-pointer for C++ types
  SomeClass *CreateClass(std::string* name) { return ImplCreateClass(name); }
}
```

Then, in the application that uses the library :

```
// Application.cpp
#include "Library.h"
typedef SomeClass* (*FactoryFunction)(std::string*);

// ...

QLibrary library(QString("MyLibrary"));
FactoryFunction factory = reinterpret_cast(library.resolve("CreateClass"));

std::string name("foobar");
SomeClass *myInstance = factory(&name);
```

You now hold an instance of the class declared in the library.

Comment: I don't have the external (Windows DirectShow) source, just the *.lib and qedit.h header, as well as dll's found on the net like Interop.DexterLib.dll